# How configure docker / pgadmin with nest

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to configure my docker to pgadmin4 in my nest js project, to do the backend, but when i try connect, show this message "Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting"

I already tried configure the docker-compose.yml with pgadmin configurations, network configurations and

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "12345678"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data/pgadmin/
    networks:
      - pg-network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "monnerat@monnerat.com.br"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "abc"
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - pg-network

networks: 
  pg-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My actual result is connection refused is server running on host "localhost (127.0.0.1) and accepting"
but i expect he open the pgadmin to create the database

Comment: that config worked for me--and I just copy/pasted what you wrote.  Where are you seeing the error?  In the browser, in your terminal?  And you got the `postgres` image from Docker Hub?

Comment: i trying run the "yarn docker:up" and execute this command "docker-compose up -d", and yes, i got postgres image, i can connect with other servers, just dont work with my localhost

Comment: Are there any other error messages? The “connection refused” error usually means the database failed to start up. I wonder if removing the `volumes` section might fix it for you

Comment: was the name of host, the @Sivakumar save me, is not localhost to connect, and is a “db”

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah screenshot helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your docker-compose.yml is good. Please see the attached host name  should be 'db'

[image]

Comment: ohhh, i connect!!!! how did you get that answer? I'm pretty confused because it didn't work localhost

Comment: @LucasBuchallaSesti When you type localhost, it will check pgadmin localhost. Since postgres running at different container, you need to mention the container name or container ip.